# Systematic replacement of ID codes in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have 3 data frames, coords, anno, and convert.

coords contains a list of coordinates and an ID code for each location. Some locations have multiple coordinates.

```
row 36381: NW_003566036.1, 1244298
row 36390: NW_003566036.1, 1317973
row 36396: NW_003566036.1, 1430739
```

anno contains coordinate data in another form, and the ID is also in another form.

```
row 1: CM001169.1, gene, 1965676, LOC100649911
row 3: CM001170.1, gene, 1491294, LOC100647500
```

convert is a 1:1 mapping of the different ID codes from one to the other.

```
row 1: NC_015762.1, CM001169.1
row 2: NC_015763.1, CM001170.1
```

I want to output a new data frame that replaces the ID code used in coords with the ID code used in anno, however, doing this manually will be horrific since there are over 5000 locations. They are not in the same order, and some of the IDs in convert are not present in coords or anno.

I tried using recode() but this does not seem practical to repeat for 5000+ instances. I also tried mapvalues from the plyr package but it strongly disagreed with me about what an acceptable output is.

For example:

```
output <- data.frame(mapvalues(coords$ID, from = convert$`old ID`, 
to = convert$`new ID`))
```

pumped out an empty table/vector/something.

I got the following error:

```
Error in mapvalues(coords, from = convert$`old code`, to = convert$`new code`) : 
  `x` must be an atomic vector.
```

using this code:

```
output <- mapvalues(coords, from = convert$`old ID`, to = convert$`new ID`)
```

Comment: It's the start of good sample data, but for an answer to be truly testable we would need sample data that includes actual matches. Even better is if the sample data were something I could just *copy and use*, such as: output from `dput(head(x))`, or programmatic definition with `data.frame(...)`; tertiary is console output of the frame (at least the pertinent columns), but when there are spaces in any field or ambiguities in class (`POSIXt`, `factor`/`character`, etc), this last option becomes a little problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can inner join the `coords` with the `mapping` table, then inner join the result with the `anno` table.

I don't know the column names, but it would be something like:

```
library(dplyr)

result <- coords %>% 
    inner_join(mapping, by = c('ID_coords' = 'ID_coords')) %>% 
    inner_join(anno, by = c('ID_anno' = 'ID_anno'))
```

Comment: it took a little jiggling and filtering but the inner_join function did the job, thank you!